# Nginx reverse proxy config whitelist IP

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I am using Nginx reverse proxy with Kubernetes services. Config is following:

```
    events {
    }
    http {
          upstream my-service-3000 {
              server my-service:3000;
          }
        server {
              listen 443 ssl;
              server_name myserver.net;
              ssl_certificate     /key.pem;
              ssl_certificate_key /key.pem;
              location / {
                    allow myIP;
                    deny all;
                    proxy_pass http://my-service-3000;
              }
        }
        server {
              ...
        }
    }
```

It works fine (doing reverse proxy, terminating ssl, changing port, finding Kubernetes service), till the moment I try whitelist only my IP. When I try to access service via https - I got 403 from Nginx. I've tried to move around allow/deny commands, but it do not help. Any suggestions where could be the problem?
Also I am behind proxy by my self - so I am using my external organisation IP.

Comment: Have you looked at the access log to check the IP address you are connecting from?

Comment: I've used same IP on Azure to restrict access to some resources, I assume should be fine. But I will check, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The whitelisting should be under the `http` directive, not under the `location` directive.

```
http {
      allow MyIp;
      deny all;
      upstream my-service-3000 {
          server my-service:3000;
     }
     server {
          listen 443 ssl;
          server_name myserver.net;
          ssl_certificate     /key.pem;
          ssl_certificate_key /key.pem;
          location / {
                proxy_pass http://my-service-3000;
          }
     }
     server {
          ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I have multiple servers. I need white listing only for one server. How can I manage this?

Comment: from your description, I could not tell how the different servers are configured, and what exactly you are trying to do, so I can't really comment on how to white list which server.

Comment: This is not correct. `allow` and `deny` directives are valid within any of the following: `http, server, location, limit_except`